# Dart: how to create a Final member Interface for Abstract Class

Tags: inheritance, dart, interface

I want to enforce a Class `User` to implement a static member from an abstract class `Base`. Is this possible, or am I using the abstract inheritance paradigm incorrectly?

Without inheritance, the `User` can simply implement its own static member without overriding the `Base`, but I would like my linter to throw a warning when a Class does not implement some static member.

### What works (without enforcing the interface)

We can implicitly use the same interface in `Base` and `User`.

```dart
abstract class Base {
  // This member could simply be removed and the snippet would still compile.
  static final String routeName = '/base';
}

class User extends Base {
  static final String routeName = '/base/user';
}
```

If we were to create a new Class `Person` that also extends `Base`, we have no specific implementation requirements. Ideally, I want to enforce `Person` to have a static member `routeName`.

```dart
class Person extends Base {
  // No warning about a missing static member 'routeName'.
}
```

### Example of the idea (does not compile)

The `Base` would contain an unimplemented static member (`routeName`).

This snippet does not compile unless we specify the `routeName` (e.g. `routeName = '/base'`).

```dart
abstract class Base {
  // IDE Error: The final variable 'routeName' must be initialized.
  static final String routeName;
}
```

The `User` that implements `Base` would override or implement the static member.

The snippet reports a warning, unless we remove the wrongly placed `@override`.

```dart
class User extends Base {
  // IDE Warning: Field doesn't override an inherited getter or setter.
  @override
  static final String routeName = '/base/user';
}
```

I want the IDE to throw an error for the `Person` Class since it does not implement the static member `routeName`.

```dart
class Person extends Base {
  // Expected IDE Error: The static final variable 'routeName' must be initialized.
}
```

To me, this looks similar to [how Java does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667764/inheriting-static-variable-from-abstract-class?rq=1), but I am unfamiliar with the Java specifics.

Comment: Are you open to other solutions? It's not possible as you want but there are other very convenient ways to achieve that.

Comment: Any other solution to enforce this kind of Class behavior on static members is welcome. My main goal is to catch smelly or incomplete Classes (preferably with with static code analysis or linting in an IDE).

Comment: looking forward to exact same feature/solution/bypass

Comment: I have been using getters to achieve something similar. The result is an easily implementable class, but the getter still either needs a locally defined constant for a compile time-ish approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Static members are not inherited, they are not part of any interface, and they are not virtual, so you can't "override". An `@override` annotation doesn't apply to static declarations at all.

You can have static getters with the same name on both your classes, but they are completely unrelated, and don't have to have the same type or even signature (one can be a function, the other a getter, completely unrelated declarations). Every access to one of them has to choose which one directly in the source code.

(Java "inherits" static members only in the sense that you can call them on subclasses too, unless the subclass declares a static with the same name and signature - since Java has overloading - but you don't get any kind of virtual override or late binding. You still pick which one you use when you write the call. You just have more ways to write the same thing.)