# Individual static variables from inherited class

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I have a class that I want to inherit almost everything from a parent class where the parent class has static methods and variables, I want the child class to have its own "copy" of the static variables

ACTUAL EXAMPLE:

```
public abstract class ConfigValues
{
    private final static Json file;
    private final static HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();

    public ConfigValues(final Json file)
    {
        this.file = file;

        reloadValues();
    }

    public static String getValue(final String key)
    {
        return values.get(key);
    }

    public void reloadValues()
    {
        values.clear();

        for (final String data : file.getSection(file.getName()).keySet())
            values.put(data, file.getString(data));
    }
```

```
public final class MessagesValues extends ConfigValues
{
    public MessagesValues(final MessagesConfig messagesConfig)
    {
        super(messagesConfig.getJson());
    }
}
```

```
public final class SettingsValues extends ConfigValues
{
    public SettingsValues (final SettingsConfig settingsConfig)
    {
        super(settingsConfig.getJson());
    }
}
```

Where when the json file is opened and all values in the file are put into a hashmap, so they are cached, but they aren't accessing the same memory so SettingsValues.getValue("settings.health") would return 100 but MessagesValues.getValue("settings.health") would return null.

What I want to happen is essentially

```
public final class MessagesValues
{
    private final static Json file;
    private final static HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();

    public MessagesValues(final Json file)
    {
        this.file = file;

        reloadValues();
    }

    public static String getValue(final String key)
    {
        return values.get(key);
    }

    public void reloadValues()
    {
        values.clear();

        for (final String data : file.getSection("messages")
            values.put(data, file.getString(data));
    }
}
```

```
public final class SettingsValues
{
    private final static Json file;
    private final static HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();

    public SettingsValues(final Json file)
    {
        this.file = file;

        reloadValues();
    }

    public static String getValue(final String key)
    {
        return values.get(key);
    }

    public void reloadValues()
    {
        values.clear();

        for (final String data : file.getSection("settings")
            values.put(data, file.getString(data));
    }
}
```

this if that makes any sense, I seem to be really bad at explaining what I was hoping would happen :/

I've come across this [Inheriting static variable from abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667764/inheriting-static-variable-from-abstract-class) and its basically what I want but I was hoping there was a better way to do this because following that example I'm completely rewriting the code for each of the new classes so what's the point of inheritance at that point, I'm not simplifying the code at all?

Comment: If you would add your actual use-case and not a random abstract example we could help you properly instead of speculating - your example seems not to have any "real life" use-case.

Comment: if you don't want the value to be overwritten for each "instance", don't use static

Comment: @Smutje added actual use case

Comment: Your `ConfigValues` don't even compile on my machine as `file` is static but will be initialized in the constructor (?!).

Comment: Yeah that's my fault, file isn't static with my code

Comment: Every time you create an instance of `MessagesValues` or `SettingsValues` you pass the file to the super class initializing values therefore. What is the desired behaviour for those classes if both should share the same values? Why even use inheritance in that case then?

Comment: I was just lazy, I didn't want to rewrite the exact same code ~5 times and thought that inheritance would help me, I was wrong.
What I want is for both MessagesValues and SettingsValues to have the static variable `values` but for only that class so neither MessagesValues or SettingsValues can access the information in the other classes hashmap, ill add to my post to show what I want to happen.